# Menu width shrinks when i zoom out

Tags: html, css

I am able to correctly align the menu bar when the browser is not resized. Once i start zooming out , the content in the menu bar comes below , I am currently concentrating on zooming out the menu.

please advice me what must be the problem, and is there any way i can keep the menu items from wrapping .

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"> 

        <div id="logo">CodePlayer </div>  
        <div id="run_btn">  <button id="run"> Run </button> </div> 

        <ul id="menu"> 
            <li> HTML </li>
            <li> CSS </li>
            <li> JS </li>
            <li> Result </li>
        </ul>


        <div class="clear"> </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    height: 40px;
}
#header #logo {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    float: left;
}
#header #menu {
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 27px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
#header ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    font-size: 1em;
}
#header ul li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
#run_btn {
    float: right;
    padding: 5px 10px 0 0;
}
#run_btn #run {
    font-size: 120%;
}
.clear {
    clear: both
}
```

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/uucsut9h/)

Answer (score 0):

It does not work in the responsive layout . so the solution would be wither use the @media-queries or u can use the bootstrap grid layout , where u can put header as a row and giving the 3 columns of size 4 i.e '`col-md-4`',
this will keep the code intact with the window resize.